# How to fix integer sort in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, integer, jtable

I search the internet till I found this method below but I can't connect to it with my table as I use drag & drop so I can't use it with my code.

I already sort my table with:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)
```

But as known it sort the integer as string

How can I tell the compiler to use the below code to my table?

```
DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        if (column == 0 || column == 8 || column == 10) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(column);
    }
    };
```

Comment: Are you sure your JTable is using that model?

Comment: *"I can't connect to it with my table as I use drag & drop so I can't use it with my code."* Then don't use D'n'D. Learn how to write the code in Java. Then **later** come back and figure out how to use that in the automagic D'n'D GUI designer.

Comment: i know how to write code in java friend and thanks for your comment , i solve my problem 

Comment: yes VGR the problem was in my showTable method which i created and i solve this problem thanks for help 